# Log everything printed into a file

Tags: python, logging

I would like to create a function that keeps a record of every `print` command, storing each command's string into a new line in a file.

```
def log(line):
    with open('file.txt', "a") as f:
        f.write('\n' + line)
```

This is what I have, but is there any way to do what I said using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `stdout` with custom class:

```
import sys
class LoggedStdout():
    def __init__(self, filename = None):
        self.filename = filename
    def write(self, text):
        sys.__stdout__.write(text)
        if not self.filename is None:
            self.log(text)
    def log(self, line):
        with open(self.filename, "a") as f:
            f.write('\n' + line)

sys.stdout = LoggedStdout('file.txt')

print 'Hello world!'
```

This would affect not only `print`, but also any other function that prints something to `stdout`, but it is often even better.

For production-mode logging it's much better to use something like [`logging` module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html), rather than home-made hooks over standard IO streams.

Comment: Wow, that's cool! Somehow I never realized you could do that. Although you're right, using a standard module is better.